# Visual Studio compiles projects with duplicate DLLs appended with computer name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have a web project which references a number of other projects, and when this web project is compiled, I'm getting the standard DLLs as expected for the project and others, but in addition there are 'duplicate' DLLs for all those projects with my computer name appended to the end:

MyServices.dll (and .pdb)
MyServices-computerName.dll (and .pdb)

When I run the website, I'm getting errors that the file could not be found, and that the DLL's manifest doesn't match the executable.

I tried cleaning the build, wiping everything and re-getting from source control, but they keep coming back.

If I manually delete them, the site runs fine, but they come back when I build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this turned out to be a consequence of the source folder being synced with SkyDrive. During build, many changes are made to the dlls which essentially makes it look like multiple sources are updating the same files, so SkyDrive appends the computer name to the end of the files to preserve changes made from 'different' sources.

[Skydrive application sync is creating multiple copies of files - Microsoft Community](http://j.mp/RDp2R1)